# exemplo de como popular uma spinner com dados do firebase

Tags: android, firebase

estou com dificuldade de popular uma spinner com dados do firebase...

é o seguinte:

tenho uma "activity sala" com as salas cadastradas e listadas em uma listview, salvas no firebase...
Criei uma nova "activity agendar" com um componente spinner que é para se populada por essas salas que estão na "activity sala", só que eu não tenho idéia de como fazer isso,ou seja, passar dados de uma activity para outra e pegar esses dados e popular no spinner. Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Carregar as salas em uma estrtura de dados como ArrayList já está conseguindo?

Comment: isso ja consegui... a duvida que eu tenho e pq por exemplo eu conseguir carregar as salas na "activity salas" onde eu ja consigo editar,excluir e inserir nessa lista. "eu queria saber se na "Activity Agendamento" no componente Spinner eu tenho que criar um novo ArrayList ou chamar esse ArrayList de salas que ja esta criado?

Comment: Activity Agendamento vc acessa através da Activity Salas? Se não vc cria outro ArryList. Até dá para deixar a lista em memória, mas creio que esse não compense.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
fDatabaseRoot.child("areas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Is better to use a List, because you don't know the size 
        // of the iterator returned by dataSnapshot.getChildren() to
        // initialize the array
        final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String areaName = areaSnapshot.child("areaName").getValue(String.class);
            areas.add(areaName);
        }

        Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UAdminActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
        areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Link da resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493214/5453684